# Is it possible to change the worksheet tab size?

Tags: excel, excel-2016

I have lots of sheets in a workbook, all with short names, so is it possible to reduce the default size of the tab so I can see more sheets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no setting to change the sheet tab size. In Excel 2016, and in all previous versions, the sheet tab will be as wide as required to show the text.

Comment: You have confirmed what I thought - that the minimum size is fixed, cheers and thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You can adjust the sheet tab size in older windows version.

http://pcunleashed.com/microsoft-excel-tips-and-tricks-%E2%80%93-how-to-change-the-default-size-of-the-worksheet-tab/

This is frustrating, I can't seem to find the window appearance settings to change the sheet tab size in Win10 though...